# Excel2013 - return max(col C) of matched wildcard pattern in array(col B) to string in (col A)

Tags: excel

I want to get the maximum score of each cell in column A from the matched pattern in column B

For example,
cell A2 matches with the wildcard pattern in column B including B3, B9 and B13
I want the max score among C3, C9 and C13
So, cell A2 get 39.17
Then moving on to cell A3, A4, A5 until the end (about a thousand row)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place in D2 and copy down. Enter with **CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER**:

```
=MAX((ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$2:$B$24,A2)))*(LEN($B$2:$B$24)=LEN(A2))*$C$2:$C$24)
```

Adjust the ranges as necessary.

Comment: It might be worth adding a clause to differentiate between a valid match returning a maximum value of 0 and a non-match which will also return a 0. The same also applies to any blanks within the range B2:B24. Also, if negative values are a possibility in the range then this formula may well give incorrect results.

Comment: @XORLX You are absolutely right and is something I did not consider. I was just going by the data that was presented. If the opportunity does need the formula to take those things into consideration, I will do so. I did however make an update to the formula that will check to make sure the strings that are being compared are the same length (Something I left out earlier).